# Extract a data table from the web page of the Bank of the Republic of Colombia via some query

Tags: python, r, api

I have tried to create a query or try to pull the data from the [Banco de la República de Colombia](https://www.banrep.gov.co/es/estadisticas/unidad-valor-real-uvr). When I try to access the table, the link that it generates is something similar to this:

`https://totoro.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Go&Action=prompt&Path=%2Fshared%2FSeries%20Estadísticas_T%2F1.%20UPAC%20-%20UVR%2F1.1%20UVR%2F1.1.2.UVR_Serie%20historica%20diaria&Options=rdf&lang=es&NQUser=publico&NQPassword=publico123`

Which gives me the following view:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhA9s.png)

Currently the institution does not have an API to download the data and I have tried using Power Query to navigate the tables, but it has been difficult to figure out how to get the table to me.

In R I tried to use `rvest` package to extract the link, but I think the link structure prevents me from seeing the table that is generated in the query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.